# Why do I get an import error for multiprocessing when my code is called from a unittest? (PyCharm Python 3)

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, multiprocessing, pycharm

In one of my modules I do the following import:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
```

This module works fine when called normally, but when I use this from a unittest, I get the following error:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/share/work/peter/software/lib/python3.2/unittest/case.py", line 387, in _executeTestPart
    function()
  File "/home/peter/current/parallelize/src/parallelize/backend/tests.py", line 52, in test_submit_ok_job
    backend = self._get_multi_processing_backend()
  File "/home/peter/current/parallelize/src/parallelize/backend/tests.py", line 46, in _get_multi_processing_backend
    from parallelize.backend.multiprocessing import MultiprocessingBackend
  File "/home/peter/current/parallelize/src/parallelize/backend/multiprocessing.py", line 2, in <module>
    from multiprocessing import Pool,cpu_count
  File "/home/peter/current/parallelize/src/parallelize/backend/multiprocessing.py", line 2, in <module>
    from multiprocessing import Pool,cpu_count
ImportError: cannot import name Pool
```

Why does this happen? I am using Python 3.2

*EDIT* I know notices that this is only the case when the unittest is started from my PyCharm IDE. When run from the commandline (python3 -m unittest ....) it works. Is this a bug in the IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be because you have the `...src/parallelize/backend/` directory on your Python path (perhaps it is the working directory), and Python is trying to import `Pool` from your own `multiprocessing.py` there, not from the standard library. I don’t know if it’s possible with PyCharm, but try changing the working directory to something else.